# Why is my password always nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a register form in Ruby on Rails.

My form current form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @util, :remote => true do |f| %>
 <div class="register-form">
    <div class=form-name>
       <span>Name </span>
       <span><%= f.text_field :name %></span>
    </div>
    <div class=form-surname>
        <span>Surname </span>
        <span><%= f.text_field :surname %></span>
    </div>
    <div class=form-email>
         <span>E-mail </span>
        <span><%= f.text_field :email %></span>
    </div>
    <div class=form-password>
        <span>Password </span>
        <span><%= f.text_field :password %></span>
    </div>
    <div class="submit">
          <%= f.submit "Register" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

My controller for creating it looks like this:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(params[:util])
  @user.password = encrypt_password(@user.password)

  if @user.save!
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :partial => "partials/form.html.erb", :task => @task }
    end
  end 
end
```

When I check the variables during debug I can see that the `@user.password` comes nil, but if I check it manually as `@user.password` it gives me the content that I input.
When I try to save the new user in the database it always has a nil password.

Any sugestion on why the password always comes nil even if the params and encrypt are correct?

---

Edit:

Thanks for the help with the code and the password security field issue. I had forgotten about it, after taking a look into the model after the replies I noticed something off:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :surname
 has_and_belongs_to_many :projects

 attr_accessor :password
```

After removing `attr_accessor` I managed to acess the password and save in the DB without issues.

Comment: `@user.password = encrypt_password(@user.password)` what it is ? it should be something like `@user.password = encrypt_password(params[:util][:password])`

Comment: Is that before or after the encryption? Also, you shouldn't be using a plain `text_field` for a password. That's a security nightmare!

Comment: Using a text field for a password is perfectly fine, even advisable in some situations. But as always with security and UX, it depends. A few articles/discussions on the subject from [ux.stackexchange.com](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/22879/is-only-having-a-single-unmasked-password-field-no-confirm-on-a-registration-p), [Jakob Nielsen](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/stop-password-masking/) and [Bruce Schneier](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/06/the_problem_wit_2.html).

Comment: Please could you post your model.  If password is essential you should be validating its presence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change:

```
<%= f.text_field :password %>
```

To:

```
 <%=f.password_field :password%>
```

Also:

```
@user.password = encrypt_password(@user.password)`
```

should be something like:

```
@user.password = encrypt_password(params[:util][:password])
```